# Identification of second order curves

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, conic-sections, curves, plane-curves

How can I identify a given curve and check whether it is a pair of straight lines, parabola, hyperbola, ellipse or a pair of curves (without plotting it)?

For example....how can I identify the type of the following curve:

9x^2+9y^2+18x+11=0

Is there any specific algorithm which will lead me to the type of curve given?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`
a*x^2 + b*x*y + c*y^2 + ...  = 0

d = b*b-4*a*c

d< 0 - ellipse

d >0 -  hyperbola or a pair of straight lines

d = 0 - parabola

`

Answer (score 2):

1.ellipse the coefficients of x² and y² are the same sign and different value `ex:10x2+5y2=10`

2. hyperbola coefficients of x² and y² have different sign `ex:10x2-5y2=10`
3. parabola only one is squared `x+y2=1 & x2+y=1`
4. circle coefficients of x² and y² are the same sign and the same value

   ex:x2+y2=1

Comment: Importantly, these rules only apply if there's no $xy$ term.

Comment: Consider using [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for your posts.